# Image viewer without large window borders

Tags: windows-7, image-viewer

I am looking for an image viewer software without very large window borders.
I don't need any type of toolbar, just a simple image viewer.

It would also be fine if there is no top bar to close, minimize or maximize window.

Comment: Welcome to superuser. I see you are new here and I feel your first response shouldn't be negative. So I answered your question partially. But please don't just ask for software recommendations without a real problem in the future :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping, I been trying searching for many idea to have some kind of text to always display on my screen then I thought of using autohotkey to set windows always on top and use image viewer so I needed some viewer with what I asked in this question.

Comment: Since this thread still comes up in Google searches... another option as of 2023 is [PureRef](https://www.pureref.com/), which is the solution I use. It's modern, currently maintained, cross platform, and a free download with optional donation - even though it's marketed towards graphic designers, it's basically just a completely borderless image viewer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here are three viewers you can try

---

### #1 [HoneyView](http://www.bandisoft.com/honeyview/en/) (my current choice)

[image]

- Open **Configuration** (F5) » **View** and

  - uncheck *Show main window border*
  - check *Do not display the top menu bar*
  - check *Do not display the bottom control bar*

### #2 [Nexus Image](http://www.xiles.net/)

[image]

- Right click and select *Hide status bar*

### #3 [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.de/)

[image]

- To permanently hide status bar, toolbar, caption and menu bar [add `/hide=15` to a IrfanView shortcut](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/iviewcli.txt)
- (or) edit `i_view32.ini` and add (thx@Lywald)

  ```
  [Menu]
  Active=0
  [Caption] 
  Active=0 
  [StatusBar]
  Active=0
  [ToolBar]
  Active=0
  ```

  (I wasn't able to hide the normal window border)

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked, but is there a way, I can save that preference for all the time ? or do I need to `press Alt+Shift` `+S+T+M+C` thanks again

Comment: Add a parameter to a IrfanView shortcut. See my edit.

Comment: I can't comment nixda's answer from lack of reputation, but to permanently hide the Irfanview UI (except the thin border), change the ini file at *C:\Users\\____\AppData\Roaming\IrfanView\i_view32.ini*. Add this: [Menu] Active=0 [Caption] Active=0

Comment: Tested HoneyView, works great, thanks!